# Access prints my word document but the document does not close afterwards and does not show up in the task manager

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access database which prints a label as a word document. The word document is filled using the information from my access database and then closed. This works on my personal laptop and prints every time. When I transfer this to my work laptop it works the first time and then fails as the document has remained open. The document does not show up in the processes in task manager, my laptop is using office 365 and my work laptop is at office 2016 is this a version issue?  Code below. If this is completely wrong could you please suggest the fix

```
 Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim thepath As String
thepath = CurrentProject.Path
'Avoid error 429, when Word isn't open.
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.
Set appWord = New Word.Application
End If
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(thepath & "\label.docx", , False)
'ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).va Me.PartNumber
'
'ActiveDocument.FormFields(fldPartNumber). = Me!PartNumber
If Selection.FormFields.Count >= 1 Then
 MsgBox Selection.FormFields(1).Name
End If
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result = Me.PartNumber
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text2").Result = Me.SerialNumber
'MsgBox (ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result)
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text10").Result = Me.BatchNumber
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text7").Result = Me.Qty
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text6").Result = Me.Lifex
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text3").Result = Me.Station
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text4").Result = Me.Store
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text5").Result = Me.Bin
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text11").Result = Me.Description


'.FormFields("fldCountry").Result = Me.Country
' FormFields("fldPhone").Result = Me.Phone
'.FormFields("fldFax").Result = Me.Fax
activedocuments.FormFields.Visible = True
'ActiveDocument.FormFields.Activate
appWord.DisplayAlerts = False
doc.PrintOut Background = True
appWord.DisplayAlerts = True
'CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName("C:\Boeing Ireland Serviceable Label editable form.docx").InvokeVerb ("Print")
Set doc = Nothing
doc.Close
appWord.Quit (True)
Set appWord = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
'

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer here was a known issue in Microsoft Office automation the document was left open due to failing to reference an object. Microsoft issue 189618 was the reference that i used to fix this.
{**Cause**
Visual Basic has established a reference to Word due to a line of code that calls a Word object, method, or property without qualifying it with a Word object variable. Visual Basic does not release this reference until you end the program. This errant reference interferes with automation code when the code is run more than once.
**Resolution**
Modify the code so that each call to a Word object, method, or property is qualified with the appropriate object variable.}

My original error catch was to use on error resume next which allowed the real issue Runtime error 426 to be bypassed. This was due to the line of code setting the doc reference as

```
`enter code here`Set doc = Documents.Open(thepath & "\label.docx",,False,,,,True)'
```

as it doesn't reference appword it leaves an instance open. Hence my second time round open document. The fix was simple. 
`Set doc= appword.Documents.Open(thepath & "\label".docx",,False,,,,True)` The code now works, below is a fully corrected and cleaned up version of the script which includes Applecores suggestion that was so kindly provided.

```
    Private Sub Command67_Click()
On Error GoTo E_Handle
Dim appwd As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim thepath As String
thepath = CurrentProject.Path
Set appwd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appwd.Visible = True
Set doc = appwd.Documents.Open(thepath & "\label.docx", , False, , , , True)
doc.FormFields("Text1").Result = Me.PartNumber
doc.FormFields("Text2").Result = Me.SerialNumber & nullstring
doc.FormFields("Text10").Result = Me.BatchNumber & nullstring
doc.FormFields("Text7").Result = Me.Qty
doc.FormFields("Text6").Result = Me.Lifex
doc.FormFields("Text3").Result = Me.Station
doc.FormFields("Text4").Result = Me.Store
doc.FormFields("Text5").Result = Me.Bin & nullstring
doc.FormFields("Text11").Result = Me.Description
appwd.DisplayAlerts = False
doc.PrintOut Background = True
appwd.DisplayAlerts = True
doc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set doc = Nothing
appwd.Quit
Set appwd = Nothing
Exit Sub
sExit:
On Error Resume Next
doc.Close
Set doc = Nothing
appwd.Quit
Set appwd = Nothing
Exit Sub
E_Handle:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume sExit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the order that you are doing things at the end of the code. You should be closing/quitting objects before setting them to nothing. In addition, I would recommend that you have a single exit section that cleans up objects, regardless of whether there is an error or not. Something like:

```
Sub sFoo
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
' Word automation code here
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    doc.Close
    Set doc=Nothing
    appWord.Quit (True)
    Set appWord=Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: I added the above but the document is still not closing. as above this works on my personal machine but not on the work one??

Comment: Sorry, no further suggestions.